# How to expect url is redirect in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, redirect, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to detect URL is redirected to the login page when clicking something that needs to log in first.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution for the testcafe v0.16.x. You can use `ClientFunction` to get page's url:

```
import { ClientFunction, t } from 'testcafe';

fixture `check url`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test('check url', async t => {
    const getLocation = ClientFunction(() => document.location.href);

    await t.expect(getLocation()).contains('example.com');
});
```

Comment: I tried this before, and it still return the  original URL, not the redirect one

Comment: do you mean the `expect` assertion is failed? Could you please provide a simple example with the page to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I just found out it works pretty well after upgrade the testcafe, sorry for bothering